# How to stop execution of custom action during uninstallation scheduled before CostInitialize?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

There is a immediate custom action scheduled before CostInitialize Action . What Exec Condition should be used , so that custom action doesn't execute during "Uninstall"?
REMOVE="ALL" is only valid after InstallValidate. So any other condition , so the custom action can be executed in all condition except "Uninstallation" ? Based on this custom action , feature condition need to be set .So the custom action have to remain before feature state is set in the sequence.

Comment: You could run your custom action always and on the feature condition, AND it with REMOVE~="ALL".

Comment: This would again result in executing the CA during uninstall.

Comment: yes.. but said you're just setting property for feature using this custom action right? So it shouldn't create any problem if it runs during install, upgrade or repair.

Comment: @Vivek : No . To make it simpler , 1 Custom Action is run before InstallValidate Action . What should be the execution condition of custom action so that it will not be executed during uninstall ?   The condition check NOT REMOVE cannot be used . Because REMOVE="ALL" or NOT REMOVE is all set only after InstallValidate.    Could have use "NOT Installed OR IS_MAJOR OR IS_MINOR OR Installed" but Installed will be for both repair and uninstall . Need to stop Custom Action only during uninstall.